# Minimizing Expected Value

Tags: probability

I have a problem which wants the c value that minimizes E[(X-c)<sup>2</sup>]

I started with

E[(X-c)<sup>2</sup>] = E[X]<sup>2</sup> -2cE[X] + c<sup>2</sup>

but couldn't continue on this. Could you please help me on finishing this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you usually minimize a differentiable function?

Comment: By taking the first derivative I guess. But also the sign of the second derivative is important.

Comment: Correct. What's holding you back then?

Comment: The second derivative is 2 for c. So does this mean that c will be a negative value?

Comment: How about noticing that E[X] is a constant, hence what you have is a cuadratic function? (this is the same as the answer below, however it might be easier to think of it).

Comment: @Julián Yes, the derivative will be done on c's value. Hence this makes E[X] just like a constant.

Comment: Okay, can we say that ecause second derivative on c is positive, this means that equalizing first derivative to zero will maximize c and thus minimize expected value?

Comment: Indeed, that is the same approach. In general, if $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ then $f'(x) = 2ax + b$ and $f''(x) = 2a$. Notice that the only zero in $f'(x)$ is at $-b/2a$. Hence, if $a$ is positive, then $-b/2a$ is a minimum, while if $a$ is negative, then $-b/2a$ is a maximum. This is the same as saying that $-b/2a$ is the vertex of the parabola.

Comment: @Julián Thanks, this cleared out last questions in my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{d}{dc}E[(X-c)^2] = -2E[X]+2c$$ so find  the value of $c$ that gives the minimum in the usual way

Comment: Should I equalize this to something just like zero and will the result be in form of E[X]? Sorry, I'm a little confused about this problem, maybe I'm hanging around the solution but can't get exactly there.

Comment: Essentially yes: $c=E[X]$ will make the derivative zero. Now, as you say elsewhere, you might consider the second derivative to check $c=E[X]$ gives a minimum.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

Let $$g(c) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x-c)^2f(x)dx$$

$$\frac{dg}{dc} = 2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x-c)f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x-c)f(x)dx=0$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)dx - c\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = 0$$

$$E(x) = c$$

Thus variance is the minimum of g(c).

Comment: A density doesn't have to exist.

Comment: Henry's method is the least complicated but I gave a different answer to accomodate continuous distribution.  I fully understand that it holds good for discrete too.

Comment: @satishramanathan Thank you too but Henry gave more simple explanation.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score -1):

Take derivates wrt to $c$, treating any term without $c$ in it as a constant, thus differentiates to zero.

When differentiating just treat $E[X]$ as a function of $x$ and then differentiate as normal with the chain rule.